# How to take screenshots while running on parallel

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using testNG to run test cases. If I am running multiple test cases on parallel. How can I take screenshots when there is a failure. I am using robot class to take screenshot. I purposely made my test cases to fail so that I can check all screenshots are relevant. But i am not getting screenshots relevant to the test case. They are just random from one of the tests. I tried selenium TakesScreenshot and it is working. But how to do with robot class?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Java for script development.

First thing to keep in mind is whenever you run Tests in parallel that much new threads are spawn. So if you are using same instance of "Robot" or "WebDriver" for all threads definitely you will get unwanted results.

So whenever you have such situation where you are running tests in parallel you should use
"ThreadLocal" class of Java on all the instances which are shared among different threads.

So if you are launching multiple instance of browser means you are launching multiple WebDriver.

```
    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>(); // for WebDriver
```

Then after this you have to use set and get method of ThreadLocal class

```
        driver.set(driverUtils.getDriver());
```

Remember you have set driver where your driver class is instantiated.

```
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver.get();
    }
```

from above code you can get instance of driver where ever you want without worrying about multiple threads

Similarly the case is for Robot class

```
ThreadLocal<Robot> robot = new ThreadLocal<>()
```

then

```
robot.set(new Robot());
```

and

```
public Robot getRobot() {
        return robot.get();
    }
```